# Connectivity of graphs

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, computer-science

In a graph, if every group of $4$ vertices has a vertex that is connected to all the other $3$ vertices can we say there exists a vertex connected to all the other vertices in the graph? Note that the number of vertices of the graph $\ge4.$

My approach: I have tried drawing small graphs and applying the given rules on those. But for every instance, there exists a vertex connected to all other $n-1$ vertices. I am not sure how to prove this.

Answer (score 1):

If every two vertices are connected we are done.

So suppose there is a pair $A,B$ **not** connected.

Now take new pair $X,Y$. Then (we observe group $\{A,B,X,Y\}$, one of them is connected with all of them in group, cleary that can not be $A$ or $B$ since they are not connected) $X$ are $Y$ are connected and one of them is connected to $A$, $B$. So all vertices in $G\setminus \{A,B\}$ are connected and some of them are also connected to $A$ and $B$.

So if $n\geq 4$ there is a vertex connected to all other vertices.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I have a couple of questions: firstly, why can we assume that all vertices in G are connected to each other (since the question states that at least 1 vertex in 4 is connected to all 3)? Secondly, I am still not seeing how this argument holds. I think I am dumb. Could you please illustrate this proof with an example?

Comment: We have two cases. First case if all vertices are connected then there is nothing to prove. So we can skip to second case when exist two vertices A and B whic are NOT connected.

Comment: Do you understand a proof? @hussainsagar

Comment: Just to confirm my understanding. If all the vertices are connected to each other we are done. So we consider a case where 2 vertices - A and B which are not connected. We also consider X and Y who are part of the Graph G and are connected to all other vertices. According to the rule, A, B have to be either connected to X or Y. This implies that either X or Y is going to be a vertex that will be connected that all other vertices.